# Why is my footer at the bottom of the viewport and not the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/acafLy9h/1/ and I am trying to get my footer to be on the bottom of the page and not the viewport.

```
footer{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:red;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

I have looked at some of the other questions similiar to this both on here and on the web, and they suggest removing `position: absolute;` but when I try this it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your html code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `absolute` elements. it's better

here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/acafLy9h/10/

i have modified your HTML as well. please check

Comment: This doesn't work in the fiddle, whilst the footer is no longer at the bottom of the viewport, it now is just slightly lower than the viewport and not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This I also found works, but messes up my title and navigation buttons. What would you suggest I do to position those how I want them? Thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: i have updated the fiddle again. but i suggest you to change your whole code, including HTML markup

Comment: I see, i'm quite a beginner to web design so this is a steep learning curve. I'll accept your answer as it works the best, but can you point me towards how I should be changing my HTML markup?

Comment: i am always a fan of bootstrap. just my personal preference

Comment: @The4thIceman this is too much for a solution. what you are asking is using the whole framework to solve a simple problem.

OP: i have updated the fiddle again. please check

Comment: not necessarily to solve this problem, but for future endeavors, something to consider. Just want to make sure the poster knows about it

Answer (score 3):

i would remove

```
position:absolute
```

from the footer **as well as** the mainContent class

Answer (score 1):

You have two "bonus div"'s. If you delete the last two `</div>`'s or put opening `<div>`'s at the right place it will work like a charm. The problem is that you don't opened them only closed them.

Comment: Ah I knew it was something stupid. This works but the footer overlaps some of the text - how can I overcome this?

Comment: If my answer helped out don't hesitate to accept it with the green checkmark :) You can pull down a bit the footer when you make the site architecture likethis: `<div>Lorem ipsum goes here</div><footer>Footer hoes here</footer>`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Also is there a way to extend the footer to 100%, as the answer you provided means that the footer is in the container that contains the text, so it has a width of 50%

Comment: I'm at the commutee right now in a hour I can send you a fiddle

Comment: Thank you, i would appreciate that

Comment: I made you a HTML5 skeleton. You can view it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDKJ8G7ZARJ1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare position fixed to fixed footer at the bottom of the page.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```